# kill an application (task) in windows using command prompt

Tags: python, windows, process, task, kill

I want kill an application in windows using command prompt. but in my case i dont want to kill the parent process. Python.exe is continuously popping up tk windows when my code executes, i can see these windows in applications tab in windows task manager and kill them too using 'end task' button, but when i try to kill them using command using taskkill then the parent process is also stopped , stopping the python code.

I want to mimic the same behaviour of 'end task' in applications tab ... is there anyway i can get the command used by windows for this purpose?

Comment: Are you sure the tk windows are not running from the Python process?  How is the tk being run from Python?  Sounds that what you really want to do is to hide the windows.

Comment: @cdarke i am using tkinter for gui....when i right click on the tk windows in application tab in task manager and select 'Go to process' then it takes to python.exe, so if i try to kill them somehow then python also stops -->tasklist /fi "windowtitle eq Tk"
Image Name                     PID Session Name        Session#    Mem Usage
============ ================ =========== ============
python.exe                    8128 Console                    1    391,228 K

taskkill /F /FI "WindowTitle eq Tk" /T
SUCCESS: The process with PID 8128 (child process of PID 6520) has been terminated.

Comment: Since the windows are running from python, then if you kill the process you kill python.  Why do you want to kill the windows and not python?  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: python main code is what i want, but not these popped up windows, there are a lot of blank windows that fill up my screen (cant close hundreds of them manually)and secondly it also reduces the stability for long run of code (this window popping is a side effect of a third party module)

Comment: Sounds like you need to contact whoever supplied you with the application.

Comment: if i get to know the command that windows run in the backend when i click 'end task' in task manager , or some window id that windows os has for each window that i can destroy.. will also do i think

Comment: The command/program is Python.  Destroy the task and you kill Python, simple.

Answer (score 0):

Taskview and Taskkill this are two command s i have used in my case in which taskkill kill the tast syntax is:
 Taskkill /IM  /F
where /F is the forcefully kill
for e.g suppose i want to kill the CHROME them commad would be:
Taskkill /IM chrome.exe /F

you will get the more info for that command on:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/bb491009.aspx